# How to extract css property from CSSRule?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to extract CSS properties from `CSSRule`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule This is a complete `CSSRule` object:

```js
CSSStyleRule {
        parentRule: null,
        parentStyleSheet: CSSStyleSheet { parentStyleSheet: null, cssR

ules: [ [Circular *1] ] },
        selectorText: '.one',
        style: CSSStyleDeclaration {
          '0': 'display',
          length: 1,
          parentRule: [Circular *1],
          _importants: { display: '' },
          __starts: 4,
          display: 'block'
        },
        __starts: 0,
        __ends: 20
      }
```

I want to extract from this object to this:

```js
{
display: 'block'
}
```

Is there any good way to extract that object from `CSSRule.style`? That object is very messy, and I don't know what props(e.g. `display`, `color`, `font-size`...) will be in that object ahead of time, thus I found it very difficult to extract declarations from there.

Comment: Please update the question with a technical precis of what you want to do, rather than showing part of the output of a console log - the desired output looks a lot like a `CSSStyleRule`'s `style`property, which you can access directly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know I can access `style` property directly, but I am not sure what is the best way to filter out all props besides those actual css declarations. This is where I am struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the CSS properties of a `CSSStyleRule` object you can iterate over the items in it based on its length, get the property name using the `item` method, and look up the property value on the `style` object.

For simplicity this example uses an HTMLElement's `style` property rather than setting up a style sheet and accessing its internals to test the concept.

It also shows that CSS shorthand rules become expanded:

```js
"use strict";
function mapStyle( style) {
    const map = {};
    for( let i = 0; i < style.length; i++) {
       const prop = style.item(i);
       map[prop] = style[prop];
    }
    return map;
}

console.log( mapStyle( document.getElementById("styled").style));
```

```html
<div id="styled" style="color: red; background-color: black; border: thick solid yellow">
A division with a style property
</div>
```